# Automated Slider with React useState and UseEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

How do I make my carousel to slide automatically without the use of left and right arrow. The left and right Method is working already.

This is the code I have so far:

```
function Slider() {
  let Arry = [
    <img src="\img\slide1.jpg" />,
    <img src="\img\slide2.jpg" />,
    <img src="\img\slide3.jpg" />
  ];
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setX === 0 ? -100 * Arry.lenght-- : Arry.lenght++;
    setTimeout(x, 2000);
  });
  const goLeft = () => {
    x === 0 ? setX(-100 * (Arry.length - 1)) : setX(x + 100);
    console.log(x);
  };
  const goRight = () => {
    x === -100 * (Arry.length - 1) ? setX(0) : setX(x - 100);
    console.log(x);
  };
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have so far

Comment: function Slider(){
let Arry =[
  <img  src="\img\slide1.jpg"/>,
     <img src="\img\slide2.jpg"/>,
<img src="\img\slide3.jpg"/>


];
      const [x, setX] = useState(0);

       useEffect(()=>{
         setX===0?-100*(Arry.lenght--):(Arry.lenght++)
         setTimeout(x,2000)
       })

   
       
    
      
       const goLeft=()=>{
       (x ===0)?setX(-100*(Arry.length-1)):setX(x+100)
        console.log(x)
      };

      const goRight=()=>{
        (x === - 100 *(Arry.length-1))? setX(0):setX(x-100)
        console.log(x)
      }

Answer (score 1):

you can use setInterval in your on-mount effect and change the state in that function.